# Python Django (Guardian): editing data depending on an m2m-field in my model

Tags: python, django, m2m, django-guardian

I am really having troubles getting my Admin-interface working. I have a Model and within that model a m2m-field to Group:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class Lecture(models.Model):
   ....
   allowed_groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
   ....
```

Now, when the model is saved I want to give those groups special viewing-rights, so that only members of those groups are allowed to see objects of that model. I use [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) for per object permissions. So in the save-method of my model I do something like that:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    allGroups = Group.objects.all() 
    super(Lecture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    groups = self.allowed_groups.all()       

    viewright = 'view_lecture'

    for ag in allGroups:
        if ag in groups:               
            assign_perm(viewright, ag, self) #assign_perm comes from guardian
        else:                
            remove_perm(viewright, ag, self) #remove_perm comes from guardian
```

I also tried to use a post_save signal, **but the problem is, that I always have press the save button in my admin-interface twice to make any changes happen** (The Groups are always added in the right way but the permissions are only added on the second time the model is saved via save button in the admin interface ) So what is going on here? Can anybody help?

**--- EDIT ---**

My Solution: I moved the permission-assignment-code to my ModelAdmin class, like that:

admin.py

```
class LectureAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):            


def save_model(self, request, lecture, form, change):
    if not lecture.id:
        lecture.owner = request.user        

    super(LectureAdmin, self).save_model(request, lecture, form, change)        
    allGroups = Group.objects.all()
    groups = form.cleaned_data['allowed_groups']

    viewright = 'cms.view_lecture'

    for ag in allGroups:
        if ag in groups:                         
            assign_perm(viewright, ag, lecture)

        else:                                  
            remove_perm(viewright, ag, lecture)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `save_m2m` method on your admin form and perform your custom relationship-building there, rather than trying do this in the model's save method. The reason for this is because the model admin [adds a `save_m2m` method to your model form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) and calls it **after** calling `save` on your model form, setting the m2m relations to the selections in the form (the value of which is presumably empty upon that first save).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, it really brought me to the right track, but in the end I just ended up, moving the the stuff from the save method in the model to the save_model in my ModelAdmin. There I have access to form.cleaned_data.